# Show that $\left | \int _{\gamma}\frac{\sin z}{z^{5}} dz\right |\leq 2\pi e$.

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

I have this problem in my homework

> Problem: Let $γ$ be the unit circle. Show that
> $$\left | \int _{\gamma}\frac{\sin z}{z^{5}} dz\right |\leq 2\pi e.$$

At the class suggestion, the teacher told us to find the arc length which is equal to $2 \pi$ and to delimit $| \sin z |$ , and I have this doubt that I hope is not very silly

In Marsden's book on complex variables, I found this
Proposition 2.1.3 Let $f$ be continuous in an open set $A$ and let $γ$ be a curve $C^1$ by sections in $A$. If there exists a constant $M ≥ 0$ such that

$| f (z) | ≤ M $  for every point $z$  in $γ$ , then

$$ \left | \int _{\gamma}f\right |\leq M l(\gamma).$$

Can I use that proposition?
and in what open set A should my function be continuous?
Is that I am somewhat confused

This is what I know to do.

1. Find
   $$\int _0^{2\pi }\left |ie^{it}  \right |dt=2\pi.$$
2. 

$$
\begin{align} 
\left | \frac{\sin z}{z^{5}} \right |&=\frac{\left | \sin z \right |}{\left | z^{5} \right |}\\&=\left | \sin z \right | \\&=\left | \frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i} \right |\\&\leq 1/2 \left ( \left | e^{iz} \right |+\left | e^{-iz} \right | \right )\\&=1/2(e^{-y}+e^{y}) \\&\leq 1/2(e+e)\\&=e.
\end{align} 
$$
But as I repeat, I don't know if it is used well or how to specify that my conditions are met for the proposition
could you explain me please.

Is it enough to be able to use the proposition if I find $|f| \leq M $? or should I verify that it is continuous in open $A$, and what would that open be?
Thank you so much.

Comment: On the unit circle your integrand has no singularities and hence is continuous. The result is essentially what your problem is asking you to do; $l(\gamma)$ is the length of your contour which in this case is $2\pi$, you need to prove that $M=e$.

Comment: To answer your question on openness, with a problem like this it is usually safe to assume that your integrand is defined wherever it can be, unless specified. So in this context, your integrand is defined everywhere except at the origin, which is definitely open.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was very confused with the definition :c